# Permalink Increments Not Updating/Removing

Tags: permalinks

The page name is /drums but every time I go to edit the page, it changes to /drums-2 so I have to go into the database and change it back to /drums which then works on the website. I even delete the revision entries in the database and it still does it. I've also deleted everything from the trash folder in WP and in Cpanel. I do a search for drums-2 in the database and nothing unusual comes up. Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried activating a default theme and deactivating all your plugins to see whether it could be a theme or plugin that's causing the issue? Do you have any slug conflicts -i.e. a custom post type, or a Post, Page, Category, Tag, etc. that also uses the slug "drums"?

Answer (score 0):

> " so I have to go into the database "

Good. You know how to go to your database. Now what you can do is to check `posts` table for post_type `page` with slug drums, but not your one... some other, with different post_status (maybe trash, maybe draft).

Once you remove duplicate from system you will stop receiving "-2" at the end of your page.

Comment: I did that and there is only 1 /drums with the guid "../?page_id=2570". There is another one but the post type is "attachment" "image/jpeg". I have no idea what's going go. If I deactivate the plugins and activate another theme and test if it happens and then go back to my theme and activate the plugins, will that ruin or break anything?